# Given a convex quadrilateral ABCD find the point K inside ABCD that divides the quadrilateral into 4 triangles with specific quality.

Tags: geometry, triangles, quadrilateral

Given a convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ find the point $K$ inside $ABCD$ that divides the quadrilateral into 4 triangles ($ABK$, $BCK$, $CDK$ and $DAK$). The goal is that the point $K$ is located in a way that it maximized the ratio of the radius of inscribed circle ($R_i$) over circumscribed circle ($R_o$) for all the triangles (The ratio maximum will be $0.5$).

Comment: What do you mean by that? Given a side $AB$ point $K$ maximizing this ratio would have to be such that $ABK$ is equilateral and such point cannot exist for all quadrilaterals.

Comment: I mean the average ratio for all triangles should be maximized. The ideal case would be that all triangles are equilateral. But I think that cannot happen. So $K$ should be a point that maximize the average ratio for all 4 triangles.